# Create Nested Dictionary From Flat Dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, nested

I have the following dictionary in which `keys` are parent classes and `values` are a list of child classes which inherit from them.

```
{
    "Animal": 
        ["Dog"]
    ,  
    "Dog": 
        ["Labrador"]
    , 
    "Vehicle": 
        ["PetrolCar", 
        "DieselCar"]
    ,
    "DieselCar": 
        ["Hyundai"]
    , 
    "PetrolCar": 
        ["Hyundai", 
        "Ford"]
}
```

As you can see, some of the parent classes are also children of another parent class (deep inheritance), i.e. `Animal -> Dog -> Labrador`

How can I format this so that the output represents the levels of inheritance,  something like this:

```
{
    "Animal": {
        "Dog": { 
            "Labrador": []
        }
    }, 
    "Vehicle": {
        "PetrolCar": {
            "Hyundai": [], 
            "Ford": []
        },
        "DieselCar": { 
            "Hyundai": []
        }
    }
}
```

---

I also want to be able to extend the provided dataset by adding more parents or children. For example: Adding `ElectricCar` as a child of `Vehicle` and `Tesla` as a child of `ElectricCar`. And adding `Cat` as a child of `Animal`, with no children of it's own.

Input:

```
{
    "Animal": 
        ["Dog",
        "Cat"]
    ,  
    "Dog": 
        ["Labrador"]
    , 
    "Vehicle": 
        ["PetrolCar", 
        "DieselCar",
        "ElectricCar"]
    ,
    "DieselCar": 
        ["Hyundai"]
    , 
    "PetrolCar": 
        ["Hyundai", 
        "Ford"]
    ,
    "ElectricCar": 
        ["Tesla"]
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "Animal": {
        "Dog": { 
            "Labrador": []
        },
        "Cat": []
    }, 
    "Vehicle": {
        "PetrolCar": {
            "Hyundai": [], 
            "Ford": []
        },
        "DieselCar": { 
            "Hyundai": []
        },
        "ElectricCar": { 
            "Tesla": []
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could build a graph from your initial dictionary, and then DFS your way through the children, building the final dict in the way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use recursion to produce the nested dictionary, and then remove keys that do not have any children:

```
data = {'Animal': ['Dog', 'Cat'], 'Dog': ['Labrador'], 'Vehicle': ['PetrolCar', 'DieselCar', 'ElectricCar'], 'DieselCar': ['Hyundai'], 'PetrolCar': ['Hyundai', 'Ford'], 'ElectricCar': ['Tesla']}
def build(key):
  return {i:[] if i not in data else build(i) for i in data[key]}

results = {i:build(i) for i in data}
```

---

```
import json
print(json.dumps({a:b for a, b in results.items() if any(h for h in b.values())}, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
  "Animal": {
    "Dog": {
        "Labrador": []
    },
    "Cat": []
  },
  "Vehicle": {
    "PetrolCar": {
        "Hyundai": [],
        "Ford": []
     },
     "DieselCar": {
        "Hyundai": []
     },
     "ElectricCar": {
        "Tesla": []
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain how this works a little more? It works for the example provided, but fails when I add another child of `Vehicle`, so I would like to tweak your code so that it works for any provided dataset

Comment: @Gary Can you post the data with the additional child of `Vehicle`, along with your desired output? Currently, if a child value does not exist in the original data, it because an element of list, and the list is the value of the parent key. However, if a key has some values that exist in the data, and some that do not, how should that be represented?

Comment: @Gary Thank you. The reason why `"ElectricCar"` is not included in the final output is because `"ElectricCar"` does not occur in the children of `"Vehicle"` and as such, it is not accessed in the loop in `build`. However, if you add `"ElectricCar"` to the list under `"Vehicle"`, then the desired output is produced. Please see my recent edit, as I have this result posted.

Comment: Yes sorry your original code was working as expected. One more query - how could I make it so that all elements of the tree have a list of children which can be empty if the child does not have any children? I'll add this to the original post.

Comment: @Gary Also updated to reflect the addition of `Cat`

Comment: Great answer. Shouldn't there be a `,` to separate the value dictionary of `"Dog"` before the `"Cat"` key?

Comment: @Gary Glad to help!